# Internet explorer 6 submit form to self problem; No POST parameters there

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, browser

I try to submit a simple form to self, but the parameters aren't there.

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['thename'])){ echo $_POST['thename']; } ?>

<form name="login" id="login" action="/logga_in" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="thename" id="thename" style="width:175px;" width="175px"/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:175px;" width="175px"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="smt" id="smt" value="Logga in" />
</form>
```

This wont work, cant for the world figure out why!
By not working, I mean the form comes up empty, as if entering the page again. Or same as hitting refresh...

Anybody know why this isn't working in IE6, IE7 or IE8...
The strangest part is that if I check the checkbox, then this works???

This question is very hard to figure out, but I am kindof hoping somebody know a bug in IE which could cause this...

Thanks

Comment: I tried it in IE8 and it worked for me.

Comment: Not sure I understand from your code example.  You have an echo to `$_POST['thename']` there if it's set.  But, are you trying to populate the form based on what the user submitted prior?  You're missing all the `value="<?php if (isset($_POST['inputname'])) echo $_POST['inputname']; ?>"` lines.

Comment: Disclaimer:  I'm fully aware the code excerpt in my comment above begs to be maliciously taken advantage of without validation and filtering, but that wasn't my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get if you run

```
var_dump($_POST)
```